# dynamiclly allocate memory for class

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-management

I'm clear about dynamically allocating memory for struct in C++.

```
struct Node
{
    int item;
    struct Node *next;
};

int main()
{
    struct Node *head = new struct Node;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a picture.

[image]

There are 8 byte memory allocated in heap, head is a pointer to it.

But when I come across dynamiclly allocate memory for class,a few questions confused me for a longtime. There is an example:

```
class Example
{
private:
    int a;
    double b;
public:
    virtual void fun();
    void fun2();
};

int main()
{
    Example *e = new Example;
}

void Example::fun()
{
}
```

My questions is:

1.I know the system allocate memory for int and double in heap,do the system also allocate memory for fun() and fun2() in heap ? if not, where are fun() and
fun2() stored in application memory ?

2.How many bytes allocated in heap?

3.How do the pointer e dereference the function fun() or fun2()?

4.What's the difference between dereference a normal function and dereference a virtual function?

Comment: FYI: `struct node* x;` is C, in C++ it's `node* x;`, unless you really want the forward declaration of the struct. You also don't write `class example* e;` or `enum example e;`.

Comment: `fun()` and `func2()` are only block of instructions (after compilation) which are loaded in to text section of program

Comment: Size of their (i.e functions) is unknown and completely implementation defined

Comment: 3.How do the pointer dereference the function fun() or fun2()? -> simply call to those function is basically `call` instruction in the case of non-virtual and in case of virtual, something paranormal happens :)

Comment: member functions of a class share the same code for each object. Only the data members are different for each object of same class

Comment: @AngelusMortis Yes,i know it now,but How do the pointer e dereference the function?

Comment: @Superxy See the answer please, I'm totally confused what you're actually asking oO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, a `class` and a `struct` are in C++ equivalent, the only difference is that the default access modifier is `public` for a struct and `private` for a class. And the datatype for a `struct Node` is just `Node`, so `Node *head = new Node;` is enough, no need to repeat the `struct` everywhere.

> 1.I know the system allocate memory for int and double in heap,do the system also allocate memory for fun() and fun2() in heap ? if not, where are fun() and fun2() stored in application memory ?

The methods reside in the *code*-block, together with all other functions. There is only **one** copy of that methods source-code, not one for each instance.

> 2.How many bytes allocated in heap?

This depends on padding and alignment. `sizeof(Example)` tells you, how many bytes the class needs.

> 3.How do the pointer e dereference the function fun() or fun2()?

This depends on if the method is a virtual method or not. If its not it is just compiled as if it were a regular function with the exception that the pointer to `this` is also passed (in a register if I'm not wrong).

For the virtual functions and #4 see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)